# Is there a way to insert dates/times into Outlook emails that are client-timezone aware?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Any email client worth its salt displays dates/times from meeting invites (.ics and others) in the reader's timezone, which is great. Is there a way of embedding a timezone-aware datetime into the body of an email?

For example, in this email where I send users several different options for training webinars they can attend, it would be nice if the text of the datetime itself could display in each reader's own timezone.

[image: list of available training slots with dates/times]

Comment: It does what you want only for meeting requests. See [How time zone normalization works - Outlook | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/how-time-zone-normalization-works-in-outlook)

Answer (score 1):

Only if you can embed a reference to a web server you control.

For example, you could have http://www.whatever.com/schedule.php

Inside the PHP you would have to would have to detect their timezone, and output the corrected information.

---

Maybe you could insert a reference to a google calendar, which is timezone aware.

---

Another way is a mail merge.

Where basically, you have a database of email addresses or etc and timezone information.  You would write your mail merge in such a way as to use the database to add or subtract the correct amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the appointment or receive an invitation, the app checks your computer time zone and automatically converts time, so you need to specify the time zone in Outlook calendar.
[image]
But if you insert the time in the body of the email, I'm afraid it won't be able to adjust for recipients.
If you think my answer is helpuful, please kindly accept the answer to help pthers with the same problem.

Comment: Do you think my answer is helpful? if so, please accept my answer, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.